# Layers not displaying in the correct order

Tags: qgis

[image]I have a shapefile that is in my Layer tree above an aerial imagery layer. Yet, the map covers the shapefile with the aerial imagery. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot?

Comment: i'm struggling with linking the screenshot. @GISKid

Comment: @CalebA [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) may help with posting an image. Note you must edit your question, as images aren't supported in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to tick the "[control rendering order](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/new-control-rendering-order-option-in-qgis/)" option at the bottom of the layers panel.

Comment: Great. That worked. I don't quite understand why qgis threw that wrench in the process in this particular case. I have added numerous layers to this project and never had that issue. Anybody know why?